How to apply texture material to a circle (extruded circle)
I have created two objects.  One a simple sphere.  The other the plate from the donut tutorial.
If I add a material to the sphere, change the base color to an image texture, say a marble texture, it takes.  Looks like a marble sphere.
If I repeat that process exactly on the plate, I don't get that same texture, it just changes it to a white-ish color.
How are those two objects different between how textures/materials apply to them?  I've done poking around, seeing comments as to "UV unwrap", and "its done in the UV editor", but need a nudge.


I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

as a uv beginner, i would recommend selecting your plate, go to uv editor -> uv -> smart uv unwrap. Then it should be much better. For even "perfect" shading i recommend watching beginner uv tutorials, because it's one of the fundamentals you have to learn in Blender if you wanna see really nice materials on more complicated geometry. I also learnt that much too late ...

Hello, probably the plate is not correctly unwrapped, hard to say without the file, please share it (don't forget to pack the images: File > External Data > Pack Resources)

I think when you upload the file we might fix that for you, but honestly if "UV unwrap" and "UV Editor" do not give you an idea how to do that, I would really highly recommend watching tutorials on UV mapping, unwrapping and texturing in general. You know it's a bit like this proverb: “Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime." Tutorials would be teaching you how to fish, giving full in-depth tutorials on techniques are out of the scope of this site. Of course when you have certain problems with unwrapping we might be able to help.

I have since watched some tutorials and with a little bit of gnashing of teeth, did figure it out. Thank you, everyone, very much for answering

In particular, https://3dcoat.com/articles/article/what-is-uv-mapping/
and
https://youtu.be/GTd8NBg8EZU?si=-cqG4PDfSJi3iKb0
were very helpful in solving my problem.
